# The type or namespace name 'ClientIDMode' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

After I have published my website, I am getting this error while building it again on my local.

> The type or namespace name 'ClientIDMode' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: make sure you have the dll of the type.

Comment: Try clearing your Temporary ASP.NET Files folder (%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[[versin number]]\Temporary ASP.NET Files\).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was coming because of Web.config got changed somehow. I saw many things that generally don't come while developing a website. So I edited to make it proper by looking into other project that I have made and also removed some dll that I was not using then after doing so many modification My project start working and I have published my website again and again so many time then I didn't get problem like this again. So May be it was my mistake or I did something wrong while publish at that time.

Thanks to all of you for replying and commenting.

Comment: Please be more specific. What did you change in web.config? Which DLLs where removed? What other modifications did you do?

Answer (score 0):

You're running the Application under .Net framework 2.0 or 3.5. You need to switch it to 4.0 (IIS, Application Pools).